# What is the invisible layer between Boolean algebra and the physical circuit of a computer, and how to understand it?

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

How is Boolean algebra implemented through a circuit ?

Is it just a way of thinking about a circuit? You don't need Boolean algebra to think about a circuit since it is made of physical components, and so when thinking about a circuit, all you need is to think about the physical components, which are based on physics. The physical components are made and arranged based on the physics.

Some articles claim that the actual design of the circuit requires Boolean algebra.

In what sense does the circuit design need Boolean algebra, especially since the design and arrangement of the  physical components are based on physics? How to think of a circuit in terms of Boolean algebra instead of its physical components?

Does Boolean algebra apply to the physical components of the circuit, or something more invisible, and what would that be? How to grasp it?

I don't have a degree in any type of engineering.

Comment: Sorry to say, but before your post gets closed, I am obligated to give you an exact answer: 'What' is your endeavor.

Comment: Logic gates (the Boolean part) are made of transistors (the physical part).

Comment: The transistor design of logic gates. A textbook on CMOS digital design would be a great primer for this.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "abstraction layer" (or level). Biasing currents and working voltages of a few transistors is a low level of detail; yes it's sometimes necessary to understand those, but if you can move to a higher level of abstraction (oh, that's a NAND gate") you can understand a much larger circuit more accurately and easily. Then : those gates are an adder, these are a register; and that collection of adders, counters,registers is a CPU, allow still higher abstraction levels.

Comment: You need a basic book/course on logic design. I would recommend [From NAND to Tetris](https://www.nand2tetris.org/) course series, which gives a good background and a *really* satisfying hand-on experience. Although it might not go into the basics deeply enough for a total beginner.

Comment: There is also the [NandGame](https://www.nandgame.com) that someone else mentioned here a few days back (don't recall who at the moment.) It may also help to understand the role (and it is only ***one*** role of so many) that Boolean logic and rules of algebra (I hate saying *algebra* without going into the definitions of group theory, rings, fields, and algebras) play. Just one more suggestion to try. It's easy to get into it, which is nice. Almost instinctive to use.

Comment: I have some good news for you. There are no "invisible layers" in circuits; all of the pieces are visible. Also, you don't need to know anything at all about Boolean algebra in order to design circuits (but it's a tool that can sometimes help you). From your question, I get the impression that you haven't studied digital circuits yet, so if you're interested in this topic, I strongly recommend playing NandGame or using some other resources to study digital circuits. Then you can come back here and ask questions about what you've learned.

Comment: If you knew what Boolean Algebra was, then you would have answered your own question. To answer most of your queries/doubts, analog circuits are labeled as "continuous" meaning the outputs can be anywhere between ground and the supply rail. Digital circuits are no different, but we intentionally use their outputs only when these have settled to either the supply or GND. We call these levels 1/0. Such an abstraction allows us to talk about state of the circuit.

Answer (score 3):

Electronics is a Rube Goldberg machine of tiny little strips of metal that under certain conditions, and with careful observation, can appear to behave like a logic system, when inputs and outputs are interpreted to represent information.

Appearing to behave like a logic system is sufficient to be called a logic system.

The "invisible layer" is an ***abstraction*** of the analog environment and environmental conditions that is used to help us better understand a system that is effectively just strips of different metals with peculiar properties.

Answer (score 2):

> some articles claim that the actual design of the circuit requires Boolean algebra

In the sense that you need it to know where to put the wires and (possibly) resistors once you know what the transistors do -- no.  But in the sense that you need it to know what the transistors need to do, or to verify that they're doing the right things, or to build a larger logic circuit -- yes.

1. If you're tasked to build a circuit with a specific function (like a [four-input NAND gate](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74HC20?keyMatch=74HC20)) then you would need to use Boolean logic to confirm that the circuit actually worked as specified (i.e., \$y = x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot x_3 \cdot x_4\$)
2. If you're tasked with designing a larger circuit made up of gates (like a microprocessor) it's function will be expressed in a manner that either *is* Boolean logic, gets *reduced* to Boolean logic at some layer of the design* or undergoes the *equivalent* of being reduced to Boolean logic.

(A case could be made that you don't need to know Boolean logic to, for instance, design logic circuits using Verilog or VHDL.  But I've never met someone who effectively designs digital circuits who doesn't know their way around Boolean logic, and I usually find out that they do when they're trying to figure out why the circuit did *that* when they think the Verilog code is saying to do *this*.  Without knowing the underpinnings, you're just finding designs by shooting in the dark and hoping something works.)

* Inside a synthesis tool, these days.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple simple circuits to show how you could convert boolean algebra to actual circuits using just switches and resistors. The digital circuits could be implemented using switches, relays, or transistors, but the overall result is similar. In any case, they can all be abstracted to boolean algebra which allows for easier design.

Below is simply
Output = A OR B
and
Output = A AND B

If you can come up with a more complicated boolean algebra equation, you can translate those into the corresponding switch/logic gates to realize the circuit you're after.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEVJKl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>